# Getting 'Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"' when applying mutate to data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have been working with R recently and I have encountered this issue when trying to apply a moving average function onto a data set.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(bit)

#grabs tab delimited file
Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file <- read.delim("mm9_rDNA_mapping_HOXA9-ER-CEBPA-degron_POLR1A_06122021-Dm3-Q25-norm_to_Input.txt")

#Averages two specific columns from the original file with 8 different columns
Column_position <- Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file[,c("position")]
Columns_5_and_6_mean_0_hrs <- rowMeans(Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file[,c("X5", "X6")])
Columns_7_and_8_mean_4_hrs <- rowMeans(Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file[,c("X7", "X8")])
Columns_9_and_10_mean_8_hrs <- rowMeans(Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file[,c("X9", "X10")])
Columns_11_and_12_means_10_hrs <- rowMeans(Mouse_mm9_rDNA_file[,c("X11", "X12")])

#Puts those averaged columns into rows and then flips the columns and rows
all_Columns_averaged <- rbind(Column_position,
                              Columns_5_and_6_mean_0_hrs,
                              Columns_7_and_8_mean_4_hrs,
                              Columns_9_and_10_mean_8_hrs,
                              Columns_11_and_12_means_10_hrs)
all_Columns <- t(all_Columns_averaged)

#Turns my dataset into a data frame
all_Columns_dataframe <- setattr(all_Columns, "class", c("tbl", "tbl_df", "data.frame"))

#runs the moving average function on my data set
all_Columns_dataframe <- all_Columns_dataframe %>%
  mutate(Averages_03 = rollmean(Columns_5_and_6_mean_0_hrs, k = 5, ))

#Creates a line plot with multiple y-values
p <- all_Columns_dataframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Column_position)) +
    labs(x = "position", y = "hours", color = "legend") + xlab("position") + ylab("hours")
p +
  geom_line(data = all_Columns, aes(x = Column_position, y = Columns_5_and_6_mean_0_hrs), color = "black") +
  geom_line(data = all_Columns, aes(x = Column_position, y = Columns_7_and_8_mean_4_hrs), color = "green") +
  geom_line(data = all_Columns, aes(x = Column_position, y = Columns_9_and_10_mean_8_hrs), color = "darkslategray1") +
  geom_line(data = all_Columns, aes(x = Column_position, y = Columns_11_and_12_means_10_hrs), color = "maroon1")
```

I am trying to visualize the all_Columns_dataframe data after it has been smoothed out and averaged by the roll means function, but when I try to run this code I get the error:

Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"

At first I thought it may have been because I had NULL values in my data so I added 1 to all values in all_Columns, but the same error persisted. If I take away the

```
all_Columns_dataframe <- all_Columns_dataframe %>%
  mutate(Averages_03 = rollmean(Columns_5_and_6_mean_0_hrs, k = 5, ))
```

section of my code then everything runs smoothly and I get a nice looking graph with the correct values and everything. I guess my question would be how can I get rollmean to work or what would be the most effective way to run a moving average on my data so I can smooth it out?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without seeing a sample of your data (you can do this with `dput(head(df))`). But I would first just trying to specify the package for `mutate`.

`dplyr::mutate()`

This issue sometimes happens when it is using `mutate` from another package.